# Configure proftp ftp server on debian so that a user can only upload and does not see the files

Tags: debian, configuration, proftpd

I installed and configured proftp on Debian using this [howto](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/proftpd-installation-on-debian-and-ubuntu/) and it works nicely.

Effectively, the changes to the config are:

```
[...]
UseIPv6 off
[...]
<Global>
    RootLogin   off
    RequireValidShell off
</Global>

DefaultRoot  ~

<Limit LOGIN>
    DenyGroup !ftpgroup
</Limit>
```

and the permission of the user directory are

```
addgroup ftpgroup
adduser otropload -shell /bin/false -home /ftpshare
chmod -R 1777 /ftpshare/
```

but I would like to have one change:

I would like to have this user to be an upload only user who does not see the files but can upload new files. I assume this is possible by changing permissions, but I have no idea which ones.

So my question:

How can I configure proftpd or the permissions of the users home directory so that a user can only upload to the ftp server and does not see existing files?

Comment: May I at least get some information why this question was downvoted? Otherwise can't improve it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

To not be able to "see" the files (*assuming* that this just means blocking directory listings), the following config might work:

```
<IfUser otropload>
  # Block directory listing commands
  <Limit LIST NLST MLSD MLST>
    DenyAll
  </Limit>
</IfUser>
```

Note that this requires that your `proftpd` be using the [`mod_ifsession`](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/contrib/mod_ifsession.html) module.

Now, the above *might* make various FTP clients very unhappy, as they often will upload a file, then request a directory listing to verify that the file was uploaded.  Mostly this happens for GUI FTP clients.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks - especially the second part makes sense. So I think I will leave it as it is.